# Django filter a day name in many to many field that contains list of days

Tags: python, django, filter, many-to-many

```
class DayOfWeek(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)


class PermanentShiftSchedule(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid4)
    shift = models.ForeignKey(Shift,  related_name='shift_permanent_schedule', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    branch_employee = models.ForeignKey(BranchEmployee, related_name='branch_emp_permanent_schedule',
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    days_of_week = models.ManyToManyField(DayOfWeek, related_name='permanent_shift_days')
```

Now I want to filter the PermanentShiftSchedule where **days_of_week** field contanins "Thursday"

**days_of_week** field may contain multiple days names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try filter by related use double underscore `__`

```
PermanentShiftSchedule.objects.filter(days_of_week__name__icontains="Thursday")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for timely and accurate response